# How to run another installed system from within Linux?

Tags: windows, android, kubuntu

I have Windows Server and Android X86 triple-booting with Kubuntu. How can I run either of them directly from within Kubuntu (without using virtual image files)?

Comment: I believe you can do that with vmware workstation. Perhaps you can also do it with [Xen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen). What do mean run "directly" without using "virtual image files"?

Comment: I mean using the physical drive partitions

Comment: VMWare workstation includes an option to support raw drive partitions. As @Anthon answered, it might not work for running Windows in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to run a virtual machine in VMware using the original installed partitions, but only with Linux as the client (Windows host) and not the other way around.

The problem is that the virtual machine is significantly different from the real machine, and Windows is much less capable of coping with that than Linux is (Android is probably more like Linux in that respect).

Apart from extra drivers that should be installed, your Windows server might complain about the system being changed so much, that it assumes this is a new machine and you need a new license.

If possible I would suggest you run Kubuntu (and Android) in a VM under Windows Server, with the real partitions as drives, that is probably the easiest way.

Comment: I will try this